# Cannot access Admin Panel

Tags: magento-1.9, admin-panel

OK, so I've copied a Magento 1.9 site over to a new server. I followed [the answers to this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21069491/created-exact-copy-of-magento-root-folder-now-its-redirecting-to-live-site-and-n) to get my site working (instead of it redirecting to the old one).

My problem now is that I can't access the admin panel.  Every time I do, I get the following message:

```
Not Found

The requested URL /admin was not found on this server.

Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.
```

This makes me think there is something else I need to get working.

Comment: Please check permission

Answer (score 2):

Most probably, `mod_rewrite` is not enabled on your server.
Enable it and it should work.
If you cannot do that you can try to access the admin via this url `index.php/admin/`.
Then go to `System->configuration->web->Search Engines Optimization` and set the field "Use Web Server Rewrites" to "No".
The downside is that all your urls will have `index.php` in them as the one above.